# Prevent submit in a separate function from 'submit handler' in jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-validate

I have a form which I am using the jQuery Validate plugin to validate.
I also have a custom built validation script for the password strength.

I have set the submit handler to call the password validation function (validatePwdValid), and I want the form to submit if the password is valid, but not submit if the password is not valid.  I have it working in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Because it's working in Chrome, I think the 'event' in the parameter list of one of the functions is causing the problem, but even with it I can't get it to work in FireFox.

```
function validatePwdValid() {
    if (pwdValid == true) {
        form.submit();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.form-validate-password .alert-error').removeClass('hide');
    }
};

$(".form-validate-password").validate({
    submitHandler: function(e) {
        //this runs when the form validated successfully
        validatePwdValid();
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

---

Adding some more code to make it clearer (but ironically more complex).

```
$(function(){
    var pwdInput = $('.form-validate-password #input-password');
    var pwdValid = false;

    // Function to ensure password conforms to strength requirements
    function validatePwdStrength() {
        var pwdValue = $(this).val();
        pwdValid = false; // Start out false;

        if (pwdValue.length > 7) {
            $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            pwdValid = true;
        } else {
            $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        }

        // There are many rules here there are ommitted about uppercase, numbers etc.
    }

    // Function to check that pwdValid is true, and if so submit the form, otherwise don't.
    function validatePwdValid() {
        if (pwdValid == true) {
            form.submit();
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.form-validate-password .alert-error').removeClass('hide');
        }
    }

    // When the user enters the password, run validatePwdStrength
    pwdInput.bind('change keyup input', validatePwdStrength);

    $(".form-validate-password").validate({
        submitHandler: function(e) {
            //this runs when the form validated successfully
            validatePwdValid();
        }
    });
});
```

---

There's a fiddle here:

[validation fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/pwmjU/)

If you type a password less than 8 characters and submit you will get an error message appear in Chrome, but not in Firefox.  Firefox will still submit the form.

Comment: pass the e to the validatePwdValid function

Comment: I tried that but no success...

Comment: edited my answer, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've used the validate plugin but assuming that validation is run when the form is submitted,  e.preventDefault() will stop the form from submitting. So just pass the 'e' along to the function that will stop the submitting.

Here's a quick example sans validate plugin:

```
function validatePwdValid(e) {
    //define pwdValid somewhere
    var pwdValid;

    if (!pwdValid) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('event stopped');
    }
    //if pwdValid submits
};

$("#form").on('submit', function(e){
    //validate form
    validatePwdValid(e);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GP5xz/

**Edit:**

Here's the updated example. Firefox doesn't have a global event object, so it must be passed in.

```
// Function to check that pwdValid is true, and if so submit the form, otherwise don't.
function validatePwdValid(form, event) {
    if (pwdValid == true) {
        form.submit();
    } else {
        alert('prevent submit');
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.form-validate-password .alert-error').removeClass('hide');
    }
}

// When the user enters the password, run validatePwdStrength
pwdInput.bind('change keyup input', validatePwdStrength);

$(".form-validate-password").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form, event) {
        //this runs when the form validated successfully
        validatePwdValid(form, event);
    }
});
```

Tested working in Firefox.
http://jsfiddle.net/tUepU/1/

Comment: didnt see that you had a fiddle already made... the setup should be similar

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple problems with your script.

1.
`validatePwdValid()` is defined outside of your `submitHandler` callback. Functions have 'scope' which essentially determines what variables they have access to. The scope of a function is determined by where the function is defined (barring use of a special utility method known as `.call()` ... but that's too much for a quick answer).

The `scope` inside the `submitHandler()` callback is different from the scope where `validatePwdValid()` is defined. Therefore, `validatePwdValid()` has no idea what 'e' is. Also, you're not defining pwdValid anywhere... it's `undefined`... `undefined == true` always evaluates to false... so form.submit() will never be called.

Comment: Yeah, I've been feeling like the code wasn't right for a while.  Odd that Chrome understands though?  These functions are inside another 'container' function, does that make a difference?  pwdValid is defined outside of the function you see here, but inside a parent function.  Missed that off with the aim of presenting less mess, sorry.

Comment: I've added the surrounding code from my script to put it into context.  I omitted it initially in an attempt to make things clearer.  The past couple of hours I've been researching, trying to work it out but basically I'm out of my depth and need help badly!  Are you able to review the longer code and kick me in the right direction?